# Apache Ant + Ivy: Publishing the artifacts only for select configurations

Tags: java, ant, build, ivy

**Background:**

I have a continuous integration system, which runs the build on every change as well as nightly. I do not wish the build on every change to run the JUnit and Code coverage. However it must run it on nightly build.
Recently we moved to Ant (1.84) + Ivy (2.3.0-RC2) and things are looking very impressive.
However this is one problem. In my system, unit tests in one project depend on unit tests in another project. I can build and publish those unit tests. But I have to do it for every build, which defeats the goal. The unit tests and coverage must only run in nightly build - not every build.

E.g. With following section in ivy.xml, I am required to build both myutil.jar and myutil-test.jar - for every build.

```
<publications>
    <artifact name="myutil" type="jar" conf="default"/>
    <artifact name="myutil-test" type="jar" conf="test"/>
</publications>
```

I have been struggling with this for some weeks now. Is there a way to publish only artifacts for selected ivy configuration and not all configuration? In other words, is there way where I can only publish artifacts for configuration "default" for given build and both "default" and "test" for some other build, keeping the same ivy.xml?

Comment: Perhaps it would be simpler to break out your test code into a separate module rather than one big module shipping everything. That approach would enable you to build the tests whenever suits your schedule and the ivy modules containing production code can include the test modules as dependencies.

Comment: Yes. I thought about it. We have many modules and each has set of test cases (Junit) that apply to the module. But it is going to be really hard to convince my entire time to breakout the test modules from all those modules -  not to mention the churn it would cause.
I guess I have to live with publishing "dummy" test.jars while building code only and publishing real test.jars for unit test and coverges.

Comment: You don't have to break out the tests of every project, just those re-usable components which are being shared between builds. This is good practice and what dependency management is all about.